# Using Reverse Index Matching How Can I Find All Occurences of a Value in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a matrix of data in excel that has a large number of values ranging from around 50 to ~2000. I am trying to find the 200 largest values in the table (found using the LARGE() function) and then for each of those 200 largest values return the marginal values of each of those values. I found a function that does this [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/434073-reverse-index-match.html). It returns a string with the marginal values, but when their are multiple instances of the value being searched for, it simply returns the same one. How would I go about finding all instances of all 200 values? Below is an example of how the data would look.

```
      | 1  2
    ---------
    1 |10 12
    2 |12 14
    3 |11 13
    4 |2  12
    5 |9  14
    6 |10 12
    7 |15  9
    8 |15 16
```

after using the large function to find the top 5 values (16, 15, 15, 14, and 14) it would need to return the following:

```
   9-2
   8-1
   9-1
   2-2
   5-2
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Would prefer not to use VBA but to use functions built into Excel, but I am open to any solution using Excel, including those that reformat the data.

Comment: These are going to be large equations.  A udf would be quicker and easier to maintain.

Comment: Any help with writing a UDF for Excel? My skill at VBA is almost nonexistent.

Comment: That is not what this site is for.  we help with specific problems to existing code/formulas.  We do not write/rewrite code/formulas.

Comment: Here's the code I'm using. I'm not sure how to get it to find all unique instances of the largest values, as shown above. Instead it just returns the same value. Is there a way to modify it? '=IF(COUNTIF($I$2:$AF$367,B2)=0,"",INDEX($I$1:$AF$1&"-"&$H$2:$H$367,MAX(IF($I$2:$AF$367=B2,ROW($I$2:$AF$367)-ROW($I$2)+1)),MAX(IF($I$2:$AF$367=B2,COLUMN($I$2:$AF$367)-COLUMN($I$2)+1))))'

Comment: Can you guarantee that there would be no duplicates in the same column, like your test data?  If not vba is the only way, it gets too complicated for formula with dups in both directions.

Comment: I can guarantee no duplicates in the same row, but not no duplicates in the same column.

Comment: Your data has the same values in the same rows....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can guarantee that no value will be duplicated in the same columns then:

```
=INDEX($1:$1,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($B$2:$J$3)/($B$2:$J$3=L1),COUNTIF($L$1:L1,L1)))&" - "&INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDEX($A$1:$J$3,0,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($B$2:$J$3)/($B$2:$J$3=L1),COUNTIF($L$1:L1,L1))))/(INDEX($A$1:$J$3,0,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($B$2:$J$3)/($B$2:$J$3=L1),COUNTIF($L$1:L1,L1)))=L1),1))
```

Where L1:L5 have your values from the Large.

[image]

---

Now that you flipped the data:

```
=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$2:$C$9)/($B$2:$C$9=L1),COUNTIF($L$1:L1,L1)))&" - "&INDEX($1:$1,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(INDEX($A$1:$C$9,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$2:$C$9)/($B$2:$C$9=L1),COUNTIF($L$1:L1,L1)),0))/(INDEX($A$1:$C$9,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$2:$C$9)/($B$2:$C$9=L1),COUNTIF($L$1:L1,L1)),0)=L1),1))
```

[image]